# How can I configure a cluster share using Powershell?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-cluster

When I try to configure a cluster share on Windows 2008 R2, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> get-clusterresource share3

Name                          State                         Group                         ResourceType
----                          -----                         -----                         ------------
Share3                        Offline                       Test                          File Share


PS C:\> get-clusterresource share3|set-clusterparameter path "c:\program files (x86)"
Set-ClusterParameter : Unable to save property changes for 'Share3'.
    The cluster resource dependency cannot be found
At line:1 char:48
+ get-clusterresource share3|set-clusterparameter <<<<  path "c:\program files (x86)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ClusterParameter], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Set-ClusterParameter,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.SetClusterParameterCommand
```

Google and Bing return nothing useful on this.

Any ideas?

Same thing happens when I use cluster.exe. Both Powershell and cluster.exe ran as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to configure dependencies for the share first:

```
add-clusterresourcedependency share3 some_network_name_in_the_same_group
```

Then it works.